# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://space.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Space Exploration has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the first full moderator team is:

[image: called2voyage]

[image: Rory Alsop]

[image: PearsonArtPhoto]

You can find them on the [moderators tab](https://space.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) — please thank them for volunteering!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: gerrit]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5372001981038592).

Comment: I removed the usual fluff about learning the ropes because two of these lovely people were already mods here and the other one has been a mod elsewhere for eons. Congrats to you all. :)

Comment: Congrats, Rory! Welcome to the team! And congrats, Pearson, on reelection!

Comment: Congrats to you, too, @called2voyage! And of course congrats to Rory and Pearson as well!

Comment: I forgot to write this -- Thanks for your voluntary service to Space.SE, @gerrit!

Comment: Congrats everyone who won the election!

Comment: Even though you didn't win, @fasterthanlight, thanks for tossing your name in the hat!

Comment: The one singular thing that has bothered me the most about this election is that only 192 ballots were cast. I cast one ballot, with four votes, so I can complain. I'm not complaining about the results; they matched my voting. I'm complaining about the lack of participation. (Those who did not vote at all have no right to complain about anything.) How do we get greater participation?

Comment: @DavidHammen We got more participation here than Astronomy. It seems in general those who are involved enough to vote are a lot smaller core group than all of the people who actively participate overall. As to why that is, I'm not sure.

Comment: @DavidHammen During the interest gathering phase, there were a lot of people who expressed grievance at the idea we might have an election at all, so maybe some didn't vote in protest.

Comment: Congrats to the team!

Comment: @DavidHammen I didn't vote because I'm a pure lurker and don't have the rep, therefore I couldn't vote. (Arguably that's a good thing because I'm not really a contributor, just a consumer, and do we want people like me to vote in moderator elections?)

Comment: @mgarey You couldn't vote because you don't have the requisite 150 points of rep. I was complaining about the hundreds of site members who do have the rep and yet didn't vote.